# Using tcolorbox (or mdframed) to reformat standard floats (figure and table)

Tags: floats, tcolorbox, mdframed

I have been trying to reformat the table and figure environments in a custom class file I am building. The idea is to put them in a box with a shaded background. I have been trying to accomplish this with the `float` package in combination with either `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`. Regardless of which of the latter I choose, I run into a problem where text in the float is typeset into the right margin. I assume, therefore that the problem is not with either `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` but with something that `float` does (though the behaviour is a little different; `mdframed` draws a box into the margin, but `tcolorbox` does not).

For various reasons, the solution should be backward compatible with the standard `table` and `figure` environments provided by the `article.cls` (on which my class is built). I am aware that `tcolorbox` allows some integration with custom figure environments, but I would like to format the standard environments.

I am not committed to using the `float` package; if anybody knows of anything better (and easier to use) I'd be glad to hear it.

Here is an MWE using `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[]{geometry}

\makeatletter
% Create a new caption style.
\newcommand\floatc@sp[2]{\textsf{\textbf{#1} \hfill #2}}%

% Use tcolorbox to draw a box around the float.
\newcommand\fs@sp{
\def\@fs@cfont{\sf\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@sp
\def\@fs@pre{\begin{tcolorbox}}%
\def\@fs@post{\end{tcolorbox}}%
\def\@fs@mid{\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}}
\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}

\makeatother

% Restyle the floats with the new style.
\floatstyle{sp}
\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}

This is a tcolorbox.

\lipsum[1]

\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{figure}
\caption{The text in this figure flows into right margin.}

\lipsum[1]

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Many thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Welcome! Is it possible to create the custom float environments using `tcolorbox` and then just `\let` the standard float names to the custom ones?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image: figures within bounds]

Without `float`, but with `environ` (not sure whether this was necessary or not):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure

\NewEnviron{myfigure}{%
  \begin{origfigure}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
      \BODY
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{origfigure}%
}

\let\figure\myfigure
\let\endfigure\endmyfigure

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}

This is a tcolorbox.

\lipsum[1]

\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{figure}
  \lipsum[1]
  \caption{The text in this figure stays within the  margins.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \lipsum[2]
  \caption{Here's a caption which shouldn't flow anywhere, since the text in the figure doesn't do so.}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`tcolorbox` offers `blend into` option to include some particular boxes inside already know environments like `figures` and `tables`. This way `titles` are considered captions and these titles appear in corresponding lists of figures or tables. These boxes can be also `floating` objects if you include `float` inside their definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{
    float, title=#2, halign=center, #1}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{myfigure}{This is a nice duck}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\end{myfigure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{Another nice duck}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was actually what I was referring to when I said that `tcolorbox` allowed some integration with custom figure environments, but I realize I could have been clearer about that. I issue with this solution is that it's not immediately backward compatible with the standard `figure` environment, though I imagine there is a way to do so.